# how draw the relation diagram of the person able to apply to many jobs, but he can apply to each job only one time?

Tags: entity-relationship

I was wondering how to model something like the college application where each student can apply to multiple colleges at the same time, but he can only apply once to any college?

I thought that the relation between student and college is many to many because each student can apply to multiple colleges, and each college has multiple applicants , but I did not know how to add the other constrain.